# How to know WCF service is called by other client

Tags: wcf

I have created WCF service, it is called by other platforms like Java, etc.

How do I come to know that my service is called by other clients?

Is there any code or library to do it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you don't have any visibility on which platform the client was implemented.

However, in practice you may be able to deduce it by looking at the HTTP headers of the client requests.

See this question/answer for more details:

[How to detect user agent in WCF web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759866/how-to-detect-user-agent-in-wcf-web-service)

Comment: Can I read the paramters sent by client and store them in variables? @Kyberias